Stiff ODE with step-like solution
Below is the code I am trying to evaluate:
wprec = 16;

Vv[x_, zz_, xi_] = (2*zz)/x * Exp[-(Abs[zz]/xi)*x];

hj[l_, x_] = FullSimplify[x*SphericalBesselJ[l, x]];
hy[l_, x_] = FullSimplify[x*SphericalBesselY[l, x]];

xi = 10^5;
zz = -5*10^4;
l = 0;

x0 = SetPrecision[10^(-4)*Abs[xi/zz], wprec];
xf = SetPrecision[20*Abs[xi/zz], wprec];

delini = -NIntegrate[Vv[x, zz, xi]*hj[l, x]^2, {x, 0, x0}, WorkingPrecision -> wprec];

diffeqs := {del'[x] == -Vv[x, zz, xi] (Cos[del[x]] * hj[l, x] - Sin[del[x]] * hy[l, x])^2, 
            del[x0] == delini};

sol = NDSolve[diffeqs, del, {x, x0, xf}, 
              Method -> {"StiffnessSwitching"}, WorkingPrecision -> wprec, 
              AccuracyGoal -> Infinity, PrecisionGoal -> wprec*2/3, 
              MaxSteps -> Infinity];

del[x] /. sol[[1]] /. x -> xf

(* 1095.054752320932 *)

For xi/zz < 1 or l >> 0 integration generally is very slow, stiff, or both. For the problem I am ultimately trying to solve, I need to evaluate different values of (xi, zz) for l = 0, 1, 2,... until the final value of del at xf has converged and is small (~0.01).
Given that I often need to increase the working precision for larger values of l, this leads to very large evaluation times. I've included a plot for l = 0 where you can see that the stiffness arises from the steps in the solution.

Are there any obvious ways to speed up solving this problem for large l (and xi/zz < 1)?

"I need to evaluate different values of (xi, zz)." Have you any estimation for a range of xi and zz?

Yes, ideally I would be able to examine a range of (1e-1, 1e5) for each.

What's a large value of l for which machine precision fails? --ListLinePlot[del /. First@sol  , PlotStyle -> Thin, Mesh -> All,   MeshStyle -> Directive[PointSize@Small, Red],  PlotRange -> {{0.0011, 0.001594}, {12.3, 19}}, Frame -> True] show "StiffnessSwitching" is working well. However, Automatic and "BDF" run in about half the time. Since del'[x] >= 0, del[x] is increasing and the density of oscillations from Cos[del[x]] and Sin[del[x]] is increasing, shortening the step size. I don't knowhow to avoid at least a half dozen or more steps per cycle.

For the numbers given above, l = 2 is large enough to give the usual stiffness error. However, I am interested in very large values of l -- though this depends on the values of (xi, zz). For example, for (xi = 10, zz = - 10^5) one really needs to evaluate l = 0, 1 because the l >= 2 solutions are small and I don't need them. For the parameters above, the solutions don't become small until large l~100 .
